# How to use toLowerCase method in amp- mustache template variable

Tags: javascript, amp-html, amp-list, amp-img, amp-mustache

I am binding the amp-list with a JSON. The problem is I am providing the array element for amp-img and the src for amp-img must be in lower case as the asset on my server is in lowercase.

```
<amp-list layout="fixed-height" height= "10" [height]="getData().length * 50" 
   [src]="getData()" id="datalist" items=".">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <amp-img alt="image"
            width="100"
            height="100"
            src="static/{{name}}.png">
            // I want to use {{name.toLowerCase()}} here which is causing the problem
           // Current src= "static/XYZ.png"
          // Expected src= "static/xyz.png"
        </amp-img>
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

Comment: I may be missing your point here, but ... The term in the double parens (i.e. `name`) is the label for the key in your JSON. The value of the key is parsed by amp-mustache. The term should be identical to whatever key you use in your JSON. Upper or lower case should not matter.

Comment: I want the value in lowercase. I have updated the question with an example.

Comment: i still don't grok the issue. please show the JSON at the endpoint identified as `getData()`; maybe then i'll see the problem. if the JSON is `"name":"XYZ.png"` then amp-mustache will parse `{{name}}` correctly.

Comment: JSON is like `"name":"XYZ.png" ` but I don't want `XYZ.png" ` as my source. Instead I want `xyz.png` in lowercase.

Comment: ok, i still don't understand the `use case` (and therefore am missing an important part of your problem) but you're gonna need to change the JSON file if you insist on requiring `xyz.png`. I am unaware of any *easy* ways to do the substitution.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple approaches, I achieved what I wanted to like this: `[src]="'static/{{ name }}.png'.toLowerCase()"`

Code Sample:

```
<amp-list layout="fixed-height" height= "10" [height]="getData().length * 50" 
[src]="getData()" id="datalist" items=".">
    <template type="amp-mustache">
        <amp-img alt="image"
            width="100"
            height="100"
            [src]="'static/{{ name }}.png'.toLowerCase()">
        </amp-img>
    </template>
</amp-list>
```